# DROP TRIGGER Customers.before_Customers_update Error Code: 1360. Trigger does not exist 0.249 sec

Tags: mysql, triggers

how to resolve this

DROP TRIGGER Customers.before_Customers_update
Error Code: 1360. Trigger does not exist    0.249 sec

Answer (score 0):

use below code to drop trigger :

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Customers.before_Customers_update;
```

Comment: DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Cutomers.before_Customers_update;                                                         its giving warning    but not droping the trigger